# Can an atom first obey Schrodinger equation and after obey the heat equation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, decoherence, brownian-motion

This question is related to [this other question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/421513/can-we-do-a-wick-rotation-by-an-angle-not-being-pi-2).

I first consider an atom in a cat's superposition. It obeys the Schrödinger equation. The idea would be to make it weakly interfere with a thermal bath and let it begin to decohere. At the end it would be in the hot thermal bath. It would follow a Brownian motion and as the heat equation is about probabilities maybe its probability $p(x,t)$ would obey the heat equation.

The Schrödinger equation being about amplitude probabilities is transformed into a heat equation by a Wick rotation of $\pi/2$.

Is there intermediate rotation in decoherence? Could it be so?
I had the idea that heat equation could come quantum motion after reading this paper:
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0310171
See eq (10) we see that discrete quantum walk when $\Delta x$ and $\Delta t$ tend to zero with a peculiar relation between them give the heat relation.
Look also to the links given in reference at the end.

Comment: Wick rotation is exploitation of accidental similarity in form of propagator and Boltzmann factor, i.e. both of the form ~ exp(const times energy). In QM this constant is pure imaginary, and in *equilibrium* SM its (usually) real. You can make partial rotation, but you must justify - does it represent something physical, or is it just mathematical manipulation out of context? Look for non-hermitian physics/qm/path integrals.

Comment: I think that the answer to your question is NO, things are more subtle. You should look at the dynamics of "open quantum systems", namely the dynamics of a quantum particle (or particles) interacting with an external environment (in your case, the heat bath): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_quantum_system

Comment: I added a link at the end of the question. it is about quantum walk.